# PHP PHPUnit Test Case

Tags: php, function, oop, methods, phpunit

Write a class 'Skill' that handles any function which starts with ‘has_’ keyword return function ‘exist’ and any other function that starts with any word that should return ‘not exist’ and checking a property if it ends with ‘_CT’ return md5 encryption for property otherwise return without encryption.

I have used magic functions and object-oriented programming.

Below are the files with the code for class Skill and test cases:

Skill.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Exam;

class Skill
{
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        if (str_starts_with($name, 'has')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        if (str_ends_with($args, 'CT')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return  false;
        }  
    }
}
```

SkillTest.php

```
<?php

use Coalition\Exam\Skill;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SkillTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testHasFunctionExists(): void
    {
        $skill = new Skill();
        $function = 'has' . $this->generateRandomString(5);
        $this->assertTrue($skill->$function(), 'success');
    }

    public function testHasPropertyExists(): void
    {
        $skill = new Skill();
        $property = $this->generateRandomString(7) . '_CT';

        $this->assertTrue($skill->$property == md5($property), 'success');
    }
     
    public function testHasAnyPropertyExists(): void
    {
        $skill = new Skill();
        $property = $this->generateRandomString(7);

        $this->assertFalse($skill->$property == md5($property), 'success');
    }

    public function testObjectAsString(): void
    {
        $skill = new Skill();
        $this->assertTrue( strpos($skill, 'CT') !== false, 'success');
    }

    public function testSetSkillLanguage(): void
    {
        $skill = new Skill();
        $skill->language = 'PHP';
        $this->assertTrue( $skill->language === 'PHP', 'success');
    }


    public function testInvoke(): void
    {
        $skill = new Skill();
        $this->assertEquals(10, $skill([3,7]));
    }

    private function generateRandomString($length = 10): string
    {
        $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }

}
```

When I run PHPUnit tests, I am getting errors.

There were 2 errors:

1)

> SkillTest::testObjectAsString TypeError: strpos(): Argument #1
> ($haystack) must be of type string, Coalition\Exam\Skill given
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Rizeen-CT\tests\SkillTest.php:34

2. 

> SkillTest::testInvoke Error: Object of type Coalition\Exam\Skill is
> not callable
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Rizeen-CT\tests\SkillTest.php:48

There was 1 failure:

> SkillTest::testHasPropertyExists success Failed asserting that false
> is true.
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Rizeen-CT\tests\SkillTest.php:20
>
> ERRORS! Tests: 6, Assertions: 4, Errors: 2, Failures: 1, Warnings: 2,
> Deprecations: 1.

I tried declaring the first argument as string, but the error still persists.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php - strpos tests the position of a string inside another string. `$skill` is an object, not a string - as the error is clearlying telling you. What were you actually trying to achieve when you wrote `strpos($skill, 'CT') !== false`?

Comment: Equally it's unclear what you intended when you wrote `$skill([3,7])`...again, `$skill` is an object, it's not a function you can call. Which is, again, what the error message is telling you. It's hard to suggest how to fix it when the code is so entirely nonsensical that the intention behind it is unclear.

Comment: And yet again, with `$skill->$property == md5($property)` (relating to the failure report) - when would you ever expect this to be true? The Skill class does not even have any properties, let alone any properties which have values set, let alone any properties whose set values are somehow equal to the md5 hash of a randomly-generated string whose value wasn't known when the class was instantiated! It just, quite literally, makes no sense. I - again - cannot understand what you were trying to achieve with this bit of code, and therefore cannot suggest how to alter it successfully.

Comment: As for `Write a class 'Skill' that handles any function which starts with ‘has_’ keyword return function ‘exist’ and any other function that starts with any word that should return ‘not exist’ and checking a property if it ends with ‘_CT’ return md5 encryption for property otherwise return without encryption`...did this have some puncutation in it once upon a time? Or is this an _exact_ copy of the instructions you were given for this assignment? Because this, in itself, is barely comprehensible and from that viewpoint I can understand how you might struggle to implement it.

Comment: i need to test the $skill object as a string and return true if strpos($skill, 'CT') !== false. Is there any way to pass the string to the function from the class Skills?

Comment: `i need to test the $skill object as a string` ... Why do you need to do that? Your specification doesn't require that. And it doesn't make sense anyway, because $skill is never a string. You can't test it "as a string" because it's not a string

Comment: `Is there any way to pass the string to the function from the class Skills`...which string, from where, and to which function? Try to be specific then we can be certain what you mean. Use examples, if it helps.

Comment: $name object as a string from the class Skill to public function testObjectAsString

Comment: In the `__call` function of the Skill class, $name comes from a value that you pass _into_ the Skill class, as a parameter. And the class does not alter it after you pass it in. Therefore I don't know why you want to test it? It doesn't tell you anything about how the class behaves.

Comment: P.S. What version of PHP are you using? Because all this magic method stuff is deprecated now, and will be removed from PHP eventually. In the newest PHP, you will get deprecation notices whenever you use it. I don't know why anyone is setting you a challenge to learn about it, really.